# Cassandra: Execution order of Insert statements in a Batch request

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I have a table with the following schema:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS data (
 key TEXT,
 created_at TIMEUUID,
 value TEXT,
 PRIMARY KEY (key, created_at)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (created_at DESC);
```

Data is appended only and to get the value of a key, we retrieve the record with latest created_at using the query:

```
SELECT * FROM data WHERE key = ? ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 1
```

In our application, we can insert multiple records of the same key using Batch statement as following:

```
BEGIN BATCH
INSERT INTO data (key, created_at, value) VALUES ('MyKey', now(), 'value1');
INSERT INTO data (key, created_at, value) VALUES ('MyKey', now(), 'value2');
....
INSERT INTO data (key, created_at, value) VALUES ('MyKey', now(), 'value10');
APPLY BATCH;
```

**What will be the latest record of this `MyKey`? Is the result deterministic?**

I tested using values with random data and found that the value from SELECT query is always the value of the last statement of the batch.

My assumption is when the batch query sent to Coordinator node, the statements will be parsed by QueryProcessor in the order they appear in the batch query. And for each statement, the native function `now()` will be evaluated and a unique timeuuid generated in an increasing order.

> now()
> In the coordinator node, generates a new unique timeuuid in milliseconds when the statement is executed. The timestamp portion of the timeuuid conforms to the UTC (Universal Time) standard. This method is useful for inserting values. The value returned by now() is guaranteed to be unique.

---

Summary of findings regarding order of statements in a batch can be found in the comments.

Comment: Adding USING TIMESTAMP to each statement won't change the order of execution, it only helps if some statements are modifying data of the same primary key and need conflict resolution.

Comment: `now() function is evaluated on the coordinator node at the time where the statement using it is executed`. Does this mean `now()` will be evaluated for each statement in the order listed in the batch?

Comment: `However, it is important to understand that all the statements processed in a BATCH statement timestamp the records with the same value. The operations may not perform in the order listed in the BATCH statement. The UPDATE might be processed BEFORE the first INSERT that sets the balance value to zero, allowing the conditional to be met.` https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql-oss/3.3/cql/cql_using/useBatchGoodExample.html

Comment: `If a timestamp is not specified for each operation, then all operations will be applied with the same timestamp (either one generated automatically, or the timestamp provided at the batch level). Due to Cassandra’s conflict resolution procedure in the case of timestamp ties, operations may be applied in an order that is different from the order they are listed in the BATCH statement. To force a particular operation ordering, you must specify per-operation timestamps.` https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/cassandra/cql/dml.html#batch_statement

Comment: `These are the rules (https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/trunk/src/java/org/apache/cassandra/db/Column.java#L228):
1. If timestamps are different, pick the column with the largest timestamp (the value being a regular column or a tombstone)
2. if timestamps are the same, and one of the columns in a tombstone ('null') - pick the tombstone
3. if timestamps are the same, and none of the columns are tombstones, pick the column with the largest value`
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-6426?focusedCommentId=13836059